# How can I modify the syntax end=' ' to print on the next line of while loops?

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple code to print the factor of a number from the user input. However, the next line of user input starts on the same line as the indexes of previous loop.

```
while True: 
    num = int(input('enter a number: '))
    print('factor of {}: '.format(num), end = ' ')
    for i in range (1,num+1) : 
        if num%i == 0 : 
            print(i, end = ' ')
```

Output:

```
enter a number: 32
factor of 32:  1 2 4 8 16 32 enter a number: 32
factor of 32:  1 2 4 8 16 32 enter a number: 32
factor of 32:  1 2 4 8 16 32
```

Comment: Add `print()` after the for-loop to move following output to a new line.

Comment: Thank you Michael! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can another print after the for loop

Comment: Thank you Nabil! That was so simple

Comment: If you feel this has answered your question, say "thank you" on SO by accepting and/or upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend `\n` to the **input** line.

```py
    while True: 
        num = int(input('\nenter a number:'))
        print('factor of {}: '.format(num), end = ' ')
        for i in range (1,num+1) : 
            if num%i == 0 : 
                print(i, end = ' ')
```

**Output**

```
enter a number:32
factor of 32:  1 2 4 8 16 32 
enter a number:32
factor of 32:  1 2 4 8 16 32 
enter a number:
```